# Create AWS cloudwatch metrics filter for log that are space delimited and contains slash(/)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a log sample:

```
********     ********        ********      ********      130594336/-1
```

Metrics filter:

```
[field1, field2, field3, field4, field5]
```

Is it possible to read the field5 till slash. I only want the value 130594336 to go to a metrics. It's now reading the full value and not showing it in metrics.

[image]